# Rewrite rule .htaccess not working with get PHP variables in ULR

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to make pretty URL for my gallery page.
Main page index.php gets url parameters tabl(table) and meno(name) to see which gallery to be visible.
I have a link to gallery.

`<a href="https://onlinegallery.online/index.php?tabl='.$table.'&meno='.$jmeno.'">'.$table.'</a>`

URL to show gallery.
https://onlinegallery.online/index.php?tabl=gallery&meno=admin

I need to get https://onlinegallery.online/gallery/admin

I spent a lot of time but all i write to .htaccess not working.
For example.

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteRule ^tabl/meno/([0-9]+)/([^.]+)$ index.php?tabl=$1&meno=$2`

May there be a problem with the php code inside index.php? Code is for redirect page if there is no variable inside url and is also the main page of my gallery page.

```
if(!isset($_GET['meno'])){
header('location: ' . 'https://onlinegallery.online/index.php?tabl=gallery&meno=admin');
exit;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? If you don't put the proper URL in your markup, it's obvious that it is not used?

Comment: Your RewriteRule is looking for an URL starting with /table/meno/ followed by a number, a slash and then it captures all the rest. Aren't you trying to match `^/?([^/]+)/(.+)$` instead?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?tabl=$1&meno=$2 [L]`


Have you tried this?

Comment: When i tried RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?tabl=$1&meno=$2 [L] page still redirect to https://onlinegallery.online/index.php?tabl=gallery&meno=admin without any changes

Comment: ....have you understood that a RewriteRule usually rewrites a **nice** URL to the more technical one? If you place `index.php?tabl=gallery&meno=admin` in your markup, the rule is not triggered

Comment: You should post complete code of htaccess. It can be, htaccess contains any code that redirect page.

Comment: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?tabl=$1&meno=$2 [L]
</IfModule>`

It is working for me.

Comment: I have no more code in .htaccess. ` <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> `
 `RewriteEngine On `
 `RewriteBase / ` 
 `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?tabl=$1&meno=$2 [L] ` 
 `</IfModule>` Not working for me

Comment: @Nico Haase. So do I have to rename my link as https://onlinegallery.online/index.php/gallery/meno and then in .htaccess rewrite rule to get data from URL ? I do not have an idea

Comment: @Jony Saini . As i wrote. I do not have more code in .htaccess. I have used some headers to redirect pages in my php files. Could this be a problem that rewrites not working ?

Comment: yes @rebosha, I think you have written "header(location:)" on index.php at top, so it is redirecting it.

`header('location: ' . 'https://onlinegallery.online/index.php?tabl=gallery&meno=admin');`

this should be

`header('location: ' . 'https://onlinegallery.online/gallery/admin');`

Comment: @Jony Saini . I tried but of course..Requested document not found... : )

Comment: without any php headers when i created test.php. In htaccess add  `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ test.php?tabl=$1&meno=$2 [L] 
</IfModule> ` I put link  https://onlinegallery.online/test.php?tabl=asdasd&meno=asdas to browser. Should it be right ? Requested document not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying you want to visit URL:

> https://onlinegallery.online/gallery/admin

to get:

> https://onlinegallery.online/index.php?tabl=gallery&meno=admin

Where:

> https://onlinegallery.online/[tabl]/[meno]

if that is the case

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /
RewriteRule   ^(.*)/(.&)$  index.php?tabl=$1&meno=$2  [QSA,L]
```

> Remember if are not using `httpd.conf` base configuration file, and you are using .htaccess file, .ht* configuration must be turn on (with rewrite module included), and your directory must have configuration of `AllowOverride` for accepting rewrite command too.

Answer (score 0):

WORKS

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?tabl=$1&meno=$2 [L]
Redirect /index.html /gallery/admin/
</IfModule>
```

On page where need to send variables to URL

```
<a href="https://onlinegallery.online/'.$table.'/'.$jmeno.'/"
```

On index.php i had to change all links to full URL

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://onlinegallery.online/js/full.js"></script>
```

Thank you all

https://onlinegallery.online/admin/gallery/